# Can I search for an object inside of a map?

Tags: java

So I have this code:

```
public class AccountService {

private Map<String, Account> accounts = DatabaseClass.getAccounts();


public AccountService(){
    Account acc = new Account();
    acc.setNickname("1");
    acc.setPassword("2");
    accounts.put("1", acc);
}
public List<Account> getAllAccounts(){
    return new ArrayList<Account>(accounts.values());
}

public Account addAccount(String nickname, Account acc){
    accounts.put(nickname, acc);
    return acc;
}

public Account validateAccount(String nickname, String password){
    Account acc = new Account(nickname,password);
    if (accounts.containsValue(acc)){
        acc.setNickname("true");
        acc.setPassword("true");
    }
    return acc;
}


public class AccountResource {

AccountService accountservice = new AccountService();


@GET
public List<Account> getAllAccounts(){
    return accountservice.getAllAccounts();

}

@POST
@Path("/{nickname}")
public Account addAccount(@PathParam("nickname") String nickname,Account acc){
    return accountservice.addAccount(nickname,acc);

}


@GET
@Path("/{nickname}/{password}")
public Account validateAccount(@PathParam("nickname")String nickname, @PathParam("password") String password){
return accountservice.validateAccount(nickname , password);
}



public class DatabaseClass {

private static Map<String, Playlist> playlists = new HashMap<String, Playlist>();
private static Map<String, Account> accounts = new HashMap<String, Account>();


public static Map<String,Account> getAccounts (){
    return accounts;    
}
```

}

I'm trying to see if map(accounts) contains an object with the same parameters as `acc`. The part with `constainsValue` doesn't work for me. Any suggestions?
I have added new object to map with values 1 and 2.

Comment: Where is the declaration of accounts? What is the key?

Comment: Did you override `equals` and `hashCode` for `Account` class?

Comment: its better if you copy paste entire code

Comment: Provide a [mcve].

Comment: accounts are in the AccountService class. Im not sure about equals and hash code.

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced this code:

```
public Account validateAccount(String nickname, String password){
Account acc = new Account(nickname,password);
if (accounts.containsValue(acc)){
    acc.setNickname("true");
    acc.setPassword("true");
}
return acc;
```

}

With this:

```
public Account validateAccount(String nickname, String password){
    Account acc = new Account(nickname,password);
    Account a= new Account();
    if (accounts.containsKey(nickname)){
        a = accounts.get(nickname);
        if(acc.getNickname().equals(a.getNickname()) && acc.getPassword().equals(a.getPassword())){
            acc.setNickname("true");
            acc.setPassword("true");
        }
    }
    return acc;
}
```

This fixed my problem. Thanks